# MSProject.Task create subtask

Tags: c#, project, task

I'm trying to create a dynamically MPP file.
The problem I'm having is to create task on other tasks (subtasks)

I'm trying with this piece of code, after I insert my first task, all the others main task are children of this one and the subtasks I want appears in a strange way.

```
    Task_0
       Task_1
          Task_2
            Task_3
               Task_4
               SubTaskName_4
            SubTaskName_3
          SubTaskName_2
        SubTaskName_1
     SubTaskName_0
```

I want like this

```
  task 1
   subtask 1

  task 2
    subtask 2
```

my code is the following

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task task;

string t1, t2;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    task = project.Tasks.Add(

    "Task_" + i.ToString(), i + 1);
    t1 = "05/12/2012";
    t2 = "12/12/2012";

    /*TimeSpan span = Convert.ToDateTime(t2) - Convert.ToDateTime(t1);
    task.Duration = span.Hours;*/
    task.Start = t1;
    task.Finish = t2;
    task.ResourceNames = "Someone";

    //task.OutlineLevel = 1;

    task.Text1 = "Task_TestTask" + i.ToString();

     //also tried with this one
    /*Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task newTask = task.OutlineChildren.Add("otraSubTarea_" + i.ToString(), task.ID + 1);
    newTask.Start = "12/12/2012";
    newTask.Finish = "12/12/2012";
    newTask.OutlineIndent();*/

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task subTask = project.Tasks.Add("SubTaskName_" + i.ToString(), task.ID+1);
    subTask.Start = "05/12/2012";
    subTask.Finish = "12/12/2012";
    subTask.OutlineIndent();
}
```

I can't find too much information on this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've solved this already, but your post helped me with an indentation question I had, so here is an answer that hopefully also solves your issue.

I think there are two issues with the above that can be solved

1. You need **two** indexes (or to calculate a 2nd index from the first). One index keeps track of your tasks and their naming as well as their attached sub tasks. The second index needs to keep track of the position of the actual task. E.g. Task_1 is inserted at position 1, Task_2 is inserted at position 3 like an array (Task indexes are 1-based not 0-based)
2. Once you indent a task, all child tasks will also inherit the indentation, so for each new 'parent' task you will need to 'outdent'. You can assume you will outdent every parent task expect for the initial task

The following code works for me:

```
int iTaskIndex = 1;
for (int iTaskNameIndex = 1; iTaskNameIndex <= 5; iTaskNameIndex++)
{
    Task task = project.Tasks.Add("Task_" + iTaskNameIndex.ToString(), iTaskIndex);
    if (iTaskIndex > 1)
        task.OutlineOutdent();
    Task subTask = project.Tasks.Add("SubTaskName_" + iTaskNameIndex.ToString(), iTaskIndex + 1);
    subTask.OutlineIndent();
    iTaskIndex += 2;
}
```

After inserting a new Parent and Child task pair you need to

1. Increase the Task naming index by 1
2. Increase the Task position index by 2
3. Reset the indentation before (or when) adding a new parent task

This gives me:

```
Task_1
    SubTaskName_1
Task_2
    SubTaskName_2
Task_3
    SubTaskName_3
Task_4
    SubTaskName_4
Task_5
    SubTaskName_5
```

You can combine these indexes together and just refer to the position index as a calculation based on the naming index (e.g iTaskIndex = ((iTaskNameIndex * 2) -1)) but I thought the issue and the code would be clearer with two separate indeces